# Missing latexindent from TeXLive full installation

Tags: latexindent

Even after `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` on Linux I'm apparently missing `latexindent`. I can't configure any command with this application within TeXstudio because I get the following, as an example:

> Error: Could not start the command: latexindent.pl -w "main".tex

Same error within the terminal calling from the same directory where I downloaded latexindent from its GitHub repository.

I checked for Perl in my system via `info perl`; it's installed.

How is this fixed?

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: @cmhughes I am *not* going through that. I edited my question too.

Comment: Did you try installing it from `tlmgr`? Did you try updating the repository? `sudo tlmgr option repository ctan;
sudo tlmgr update --self;
sudo tlmgr install latexindent`

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman After the second command I obtain `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.`

Comment: Try the last command only. Alternatively, you could try installing the latest 2018 texlive verison. You can see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details on this.

Comment: You can try removing it and reinstalling it again first:
`sudo tlmgr remove latexindent`. Or `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall latexmk`, but I still think you should upgrade your texlive installation :)

Comment: Try removing the `.pl` extension so it's called as just `latexindent` not `latexindent.pl`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, thank you. You've done it. I was up to date with TeXLive 2018 installed, by the way.

Comment: @useranonis the error message you presented "`tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)` " begs to differ and that TeXLive2018 is not installed, but 2017. You can check `tlmgr --version` to make sure.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman You're correct. Strangely, the installation directory has the folder `root\usr\local\texlive\2018`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot All the manual examples gave the extension`.pl`; how irritating...

Comment: @useranonis It's `latexindent.pl` if you download it. Also if you do `ls -l \`which latexindent\`` you will see that it's actually calling the `.pl` file!

In regards to the version, what does `echo $PATH` give you?

Comment: Please see the first two paragraphs of Section 3 of the manual, in particular *In what follows, we will always refer to latexindent.pl, but depending on your operating system and preference, you might substitute latexindent.exe or simply latexindent.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX Live on Unix-like systems creates symbolic links from the `bin/`*architecture* directory to the relevant script, but the symbolic file links always omit the file extensions. For example, `bin/x86_64-linux/latexindent` links to `../../texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/latexindent.pl`

This is more consistent with Unix file naming schemes, but the scripts are often distributed with an extension for the benefit of non-Unix-like systems, such as Windows. Since the script is distributed and is on CTAN with the extension, the manual often references the script name with the extension. (If the package/script author isn't aware of this behaviour then they won't think to mention it in the manual.)

Conversely, TeX distributions on Windows may convert the script into an executable, in which case the extension becomes `.exe` (such as `latexindent.exe`).

As [@cmhughes commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431305/missing-latexindent-from-texlive-full-installation/431325?noredirect=1#comment1080811_431325) below [section 3 of the `latexindent` manual](http://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-how-to-use.html) states:

> In what follows, we will always refer to `latexindent.pl`, but depending
>   on your operating system and preference, you might substitute
>   `latexindent.exe` or simply `latexindent`.

Comment: +1 many thanks for this :) You might reference the first few paragraphs of Section 3 of the manual available via texdoc latexindent as a PDF and online at http://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-how-to-use.html

Comment: *In what follows, we will always refer to latexindent.pl, but depending on your operating system and preference, you might substitute latexindent.exe or simply latexindent.*

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you for the reference. (I thought it might help to have a more general answer, with `latexindent` as an example.) It's caught me out with `makeglossaries-lite.lua`.

Comment: very nice :) I think your answer is great, and very helpful. I'm just going to note here that unix/linux terminals have an autocomplete feature when pressing the `TAB` button. For example, when I type `latex` at the terminal and then press `TAB` I receive a list of all of the different executables available to me that begin with `latex`. In this case, it includes `latexindent`.